# Fragment Caching In Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I have a partial that pulls in weather data using the Barometer gem. The problem is that each time the page is loaded the gem is pulling in the weather feed again. Is it possible to cache the partial using fragment caching but only have that cached version to be good for say 3-4 hours? That way the weather data will stay current and the gem won't have to pull in brand new data each time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the `cache` helper function takes 3 arguments :

```
  def cache(name = {}, options = nil, &block)
    if controller.perform_caching
      safe_concat(fragment_for(name, options, &block))
    else
      yield
    end

    nil
  end
```

if you provide an expiration key in the second argument it will be passed on to `write_fragment` and eventually the cache itself.

Like this :

```
-cache "cache_path", :expires => 3.hours do
  =cached_fragment_code
```

I recommend reading into `ActionView::Helpers::CacheHelper` for more info.

Comment: Thanks but could you perhaps point me to where it says anything pertaining to the :expires option? I've looking at [ttp://api.rubyonrails.org/](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CacheHelper.html) but there doesn't seem to be much there

Comment: It doesn't exactly say it, you have to read between the lines. The `options` argument eventually gets sent to `Rails.cache.write(key, options, value)` so it takes any options that `Rails.cache.write` takes. You can look into the documentation for whatever version of Rails cacheing you're using to get more details on that method, but I think they all understand `:expires`